# Forward Key Press from QGraphicsView

Tags: c++, qt, signals, qwidget, slot

I'm attempting to forward all key press events from my QGraphicsView to a widget that is currently on the scene.

My QGraphicsView looks like this:

```
Character_controller::Character_controller(Game_state * game_state) : Game_base_controller(game_state) {

        this->character = new Character(this->game_state);

        this->scene->addWidget(this->character);

        connect(this, SIGNAL(keyPress(QKeyEvent *)), this->character, SLOT(update()));

    }
```

And then, my character which subclasses QWidget, which should recieve all keypress events

```
Character::Character(Game_state * game_state) : Base_object(game_state) {


}

Character::~Character() {





}

void Character::update() {

    cout << "HELLO FROM TIMER CONNECTED ITEM" << endl;


}
```

For some reason, this isn't working. How can I forward all keypress events from the view to my character?

The error I get is this:

Object::connect: No such signal game::Character_controller::keyPress(QKeyEvent *) in implementation/game_controllers/character_controller.cpp:21

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`keyPress(QKeyEvent*)` doesn't exist as a signal, hence the error message that you're getting.  As such, you can't do this:

```
connect(this, SIGNAL(keyPress(QKeyEvent *)), this->character, SLOT(update()));
```

In order to capture key press events in your graphics view, you will need to override the `keyPressEvent` function:

```
void Character_controller::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent* event)
{
   // Call functions on your character here.
   switch (event->key())
   {
   case Qt::Key_A:
       character->moveLeft(); // For example
       break;
   case Qt::Key_D:
       character->moveRight(); // For example
       break;
   ...
   }

   // Otherwise pass to QGraphicsView.
   QGraphicsView::keyPressEvent(event);
}
```

You could just pass the `QKeyEvent` to the character to manage its own key presses, but you might find it difficult to ensure that different items in your scene don't rely on the same key(s) if you don't keep all your key press handling code in one place.

Comment: Hello, I'm trying this and it does not seem to be working. My character_controller inherits my base_controller and I tried implementing it on both but to no avail. Once I can get it incorporated on here, I can signal my character class

Comment: @JonMorehouse Your `base_controller` inherits from `QGraphicsView`, right?

Comment: yep, I think the problem is coming about because I need to filter events throughuot my views. IE: from the base view to the other inherited views since these can change ...

Comment: First thing to check is that the keyPressEvent handler is even being called when you place focus on the graphics view and then press a key on your keyboard.  You can do this by just printing something out from the handler.

Comment: Everything worked great when I connected this view to the main.cpp instantiation of the window. The top level window will always intercept events.

Answer (score 3):

You have to override the keyPressEvent event to capture key press events